# Can I find the ABV of Cider using Original and Final Gravity

Tags: cider, alcohol-content

If I have the original gravity and final gravity of my hard cider (as measured by my hydrometer), do I determine the ABV using the same formula I would for beer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, sugar is sugar and yeast convert sugar to alcohol just the same in beer as in cider.  (OG - FG) * .131 (or .135 or whatever).

Comment: Or, if you're unable to find the calculator application on your computer (Windows 8?), you can use Google to find an alcohol calculator like [this](http://www.brewersfriend.com/abv-calculator/) one.

Comment: What are the .131 or .135 magic numbers?

Comment: I have been using .132, but I think the real number .1315 or something close...  I also have seen another formula:  (OG-FG) / 7.36 but I never used this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this ABV calculator:

http://www.rooftopbrew.net/abv.php

put your numbers in and bobs your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the gravity drop and this varies the choice of factor.There is no constant factor.
See Moderator Mr Roads answer to me.

Answer (score -1):

you can check below link for source codes of bew calculatos https://github.com/coolfuturefbiagent/calculators

Comment: If you can read PHP and the application is right, one might extract the logic for calculating ABV, as well as logic for other brewing related things.  Might be interesting to some, but this does not provide an answer.